# WebView overlap the entire Compose screen

Tags: android, html, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use WebView on compose screen just to show the **html content**. But for reasons
unknown to me it overlap the entire screen.

Html content:

```html
"<p><strong></strong></p> \n<p><span>Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test <a href=\"https://domopult.ru/\">link</a></span></p> \n<span><br></span> \n<p><span><strong>List 1:</strong></span></p> \n<p></p> \n<ul> \n <li>element 1 </li> \n <li>element 2 </li> \n <li>element 3 </li> \n</ul> \n<p></p> \n<br> \n<p><strong>List 2:</strong><br></p> \n<ol> \n <li>Element 1 </li> \n <li>Element 2 </li> \n <li>Element 3</li> \n</ol> \n<p></p>"
```

That is how it should looks like:

[image]

That is how it realy looks like:

[image]

I tried to use `Html.fromHtml(...)` and `HtmlCompat.fromHtml(...)` with the regular `Text(text: AnnotatedString)` composable. But these classes can't decode `<ol>` and `<p>` tags correctly.

Code snippet:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ServiceDescription(
    service: Service,
    onImageClick: () -> Unit
) {
    val serviceDescription = service.description ?: ""

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        AttachedImages(
            images = service.files,
            onImageClick = { image -> onImageClick() }
        )
        ServiceName(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            serviceName = service.name ?: ""
        )
        if (service.hasPrice()) {
            ServicePrice(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                price = service.price,
                productName = service.productName ?: "",
                priceDescription = service.priceDescription ?: ""
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))

        if (service.hasDescription()) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.request_description),
                    color = ColorDomopult.BasicOnBgPrimary,
                    style = DomopultTypography.body1,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W600
                )

                AndroidView(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    factory = { context ->
                        WebView(context).apply {
                            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                            )
                            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                            loadDataWithBaseURL(
                                null,
                                serviceDescription,
                                "html",
                                "utf-8",
                                null,
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course if I use `loadUrl("https://www.google.com")`
instead of `loadDataWithBaseURL(....)` , the UI state would be as expected.

[image]

How do I show html content inside WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Yap from [ComposeMpp](https://t.me/compose_mpp) community.

Need to use `.clipToBounds()` modifier.

```kotlin
AndroidView(
  modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
      .clipToBounds(),
  factory = { context ->
    WebView(context).apply {
      layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
      )               
      setBackgroundColor(ColorDomopult.BasicBgPrimary.toArgb())
      settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
      loadDataWithBaseURL(
        null,
        service.description ?: "",
        "text/html",
        "utf-8",
        null
      )
    }
  }
)
```